# What is this giant mosquito-like insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this bug in my kitchen in this morning, in a suburb of Houston Texas, about 30 miles Northwest of downtown. It was on the wall, and when I went in for a closer look, it quickly flew away - up towards the light, then crash landed behind the refrigerator where I hit it with bug spray.

It looks sort of like a mosquito, but much much larger.
Everything I find online about "giant mosquitoes" points to the [Crane fly or "mosquito hawk"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crane_fly) - which I've seen plenty of (very common here). I'm no expert, but this doesn't look like a cranefly.

I also read that giant mosquitoes are known to hatch after hurricanes, and there was just a huge one <200 miles from me. But those accounts speak of smaller insects (albeit, still very large for a mosquito).

For example, this [article about "gallinippers" in North Carolina](https://www.cnn.com/2018/10/09/health/giant-mosquitoes-north-carolina-hurricane-bn/index.html), speaks of mosquitoes only the size of a penny.

I did not think to put a coin in the shot for reference, but based on the size of the paper towel underneath it, it must be at least the size of a quarter.

Is this even related to a mosquito? What could it be?

[image: with measurements]
[image: top of insect]
[image: front of insect]
[image: rear of insect]

Answer (score 4):

The better entymologists among us may need to correct me, but I believe you are looking at a [robber fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asilidae), especially based on the characteristic long, tapering abdomen, as well as the proboscis that reminded you of a mosquito and the large size.

I see a couple people posting images from Texas that look a bit like yours (especially the all-black body) on [Google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=robber+fly+texas&tbm=isch) but none of these mention a genus/species for me to dig further on. [Bromley, S. W. (1934). The robber flies of Texas (Diptera, Asilidae). Annals of the Entomological Society of America, 27(1), 74-113.](https://doi.org/10.1093/aesa/27.1.74) may be useful but is a bit too deep for me to dig into for you.

Comment: iNaturalist has over 9000 user-submitted photos of robber flies (family Asilidae) from Texas alone, breaking down into 9 sub-families, (I don't know how many genera) and further into 96 species. Here is the breakdown into 9 subfamilies ... I can't tell which one it belongs to: https://inaturalist.ca/taxa/47982-Asilidae/browse_photos?grouping=taxon_id&place_id=18

Comment: Bromley 1934 is also available [here](http://reader.library.cornell.edu/docviewer/digital?id=chla5077679_4195_001#page/98/mode/1up); the advantage to this copy is it's free of charge, but printing (if desired) is one-page-at-a-time.  Other disadvantages include the age of the work (it is almost certain that more species are presently known from Texas), the need for specialist vocabulary, and the paucity of illustrations.